# Correct way to validate single value corresponding to located value in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

The title is unclear, but I'm not sure how to best articulate.

I have a data dump of customer invoices.

In the data dump, I have invoice information, customer ID, and customer Name.
Each name should correspond to exactly 1 ID, but each customer may have multiple invoices(each row is a unique invoice).

```
invoice_list = pd.read_csv('invoices.csv', keep_default_na=False)
cust = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(cwd, 'work_folder', 'debtor_list.csv'))

for i in invoice_list.customer_id.unique():
    if i not in cust.customer_id.unique():
        data = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[i,], 'customer_name':[invoice_list.loc[invoice_list.customer_id == i, 'customer_name'].min(),]})
        cust = cust.append(data)
        del(data)
```

My question: Is there a correct, roughly straightforward way to locate a customer name via its ID and validate that there is only one value for that customer ID rather than using "min()"

Comment: If you `s = df.groupby('customer_name').customer_id.nunique()` you'll get a `Series` with the number of unique IDs per name. `s[s>1].index` then gives the list of names with duplicate `IDs`